# android uiautomator runtest error didn't find class

Tags: java, android, jar, runtimeexception, android-uiautomator

recent i tryied getting started with android uiautomation testing.

The tutorial from the developer site I've worked through a few times and after having some problems and solving them now I have got a bigger issue.

I created a project, imported the two jar files and builded a java testcase scenario (the one from the tutorial.)
after that I created  an uitest projekt with shell command line. updated the build.xml created a jar file and pushed it onto my device.

As far as good everything worked nicely upon this point.

But tryin to run my tests with the command line:

```
adb -s <ANDROID_SERIAL> shell uiautomator runtest DeviceUnlocker.jar -c c.d.d.DeviceUnlocker
```

I only get the error:

> INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg = java.lang.RuntimeException
> INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=Didn't find class "c.d.d.DeviceUnlockingPseudoCodeTest on Path: /system/framework/android.test.runner.jar: /system/framework/uiautomator.jar:: /data/local/tmp/DeviceUnlocker.jar
>
> INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0

Comment: can you please post part of your code ?

Comment: the parts of my code were espacially the one from the developer site 
[Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html)and form this site:
 [EveryOneTests](http://everybodytests.blogspot.de/2013/01/unlocking-your-android-test-devices.html)
The only other code parts from myself were adding the build.xml file with the code from my answer

Comment: please post logcat dump also so we can check where is RuntimeException coming.

Comment: @ErikMueller Did you manage to get a valid answer? I see a lot of answers but none accepted. I have a similar problem but none of these worked, so I left a question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/32200292/347119.
Thanks if you can help me somehow.

Comment: @EdisonSpencer none of the posted worked for me. But I had to say, that I havent tried in recent times. It may be that some errors have been resolved in recent updates from android sdk. are you running the tests inside eclipse or android studio? A college of me did got the tests to work by writing some bash scripts.

Comment: Hi @ErikMueller, I was following the steps shown here (https://goo.gl/LxaJWN), so what I did was create an Eclipse Project and add the relevant dependencies. But now the application project have been exported to Android Studio, maybe I should try using the "test" package created by Android Studio? Can your colleague say something on my post? Thanks

Comment: Finally UI Automation has been ported to Android Studio, so try to run your tests under Android Studio, it's a lot less complicated!

Answer (score 1):

okay the easiest way is to only create inside eclipse a new android junit projekt.

i think this is more or less equal to uiautomator. 
and i think you might have the same oportunities ... correct me if i'm wrong...

uiautomator is still not running... and i also found some bugs in the uibuild.xml from android itself

`<target name="test" description="Runs tests">
        <!-- todo: fix this -->
        <fail message="Launching tests from Ant not supported yet" />`

```
     <exec executable="${adb}" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="${adb.device.arg}" />
        <arg value="shell" />
        <arg value="uiautomator" />
        <arg value="runtest" />
        <arg value="${out.filename}" />
        <arg value="-e" />
        <arg value="class" />
        <arg value="com.android.uiautomator.samples.skeleton.DemoTestCase" />
    </exec>
</target>`
```

thanks for your help. for me uiautomator is no option anymore.
regards

Answer (score 0):

1. new JavaProjekt (import JUnit android.jar uiautomator.jar
2. create packages c.d.d
3. Copy TestCase Device Unlocking pseudoTestCase into Projekt
4. run cmd 
   4.1. "set ANDROID_HOME=" to sdk location 
   4.2. \tools\ android create uitestprojekt -n name -t "android-16" -p projPath
5. edit build.xml that was created from create command: 
   added code:

`<delete dir="jar"/>`

`<mkdir dir="jar" />`

```
<javac destdir="bin" encoding="UTF-8" debug="on" target="1.6" includeantruntime="false"> 
    <src path="src" /> 
</javac> 
<jar destfile="jar/uiautomator.jar"> 
     <fileset dir="bin" /> 
</jar>
```

1. run as antbuild
2. cmd -> cd ANDROID_HOME-> cd  platform-tools
3. adb push /jar/uiautomator.jar data/local/tmp
4. adb -s  shell uiautomator runtest DeviceUnlocker.jar -c c.d.d.DeviceUnlocker

that were all steps i've done

thanks

Comment: did it compile properly ? was it showing any line with `[javac]` ? your project path mentioned in the `create` command is correct ? try `ant clean build` ? Still fails--> then could you just try some basic code(say just wake up device) alone in your class and run..Because i had the similar issue, then i had to clear all the above `?` one by one. and it works for me.

Comment: well after running this line in shell about a houndret times i think i got my link right also copy pasting the link brought no efford. 
well i run the ant build in eclipse ide because my system environment variable was not set for ant and i had no idea where to find it inside eclipse. what were you cleaning above? i can only see a questionmark :-)

Comment: and yes in eclipse it shows the lines javac and building jarfile

Comment: did you try it from `shell` or `cmd`, outside eclipse. ?

Comment: cmd y is there any difference? by mentioning this question i've seen by now that there is besides the cmd also a shell.. waow wtf i've never seen that before

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've compiled the java classes into **android dex**!

I've met the same issue when put a pure java "jar" package to /data/tmp/.

Assume your project is `device-unlock`:

```
cd device-unlock
android create uitest-project -n device-unlock -t 1 -p .
and build
```

Now you'll find the dexed jar package in `bin/device-unlock.jar`, open it with zip you'll see a `classes.dex`.

With this jar, it should be ok to continue your test.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and made a quick haxx to fix it:

**Solve it by:**

1. go to you UiautomationTest project and from the bin/ folder copy
   the classfile(s). In my case I copied the whole folderstructure
   com/poc/MyTest.class
2. go to the App-Under-Test project and in the
   bin/ folder past the class data. In my case the com/poc/MyTest.class
   is merged with the existing classes under com/
3. Re-build the UiAutomation project with "ant build"
4. re-deploy and now you can run it!

This is just a workaround but it identified the root case - that the testcase class is excluded from the UiAutomator buildstep

Answer (score 0):

While running the uiautomator Tests command run it in the below way

Example:

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest LaunchSettings.jar -c com.uia.example.my.LaunchSettings
adb shell uiautomator runtest "jar name" -c "packagename"."Classname"
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to check this problem is to run this command without using `-c <classpath>#<testMethod>` and check if it works. 
If it works check for the class name that it prints in the terminal is the one that's used with -c

```
adb -s shell uiautomator runtest DeviceUnlocker.jar
```