# Any difference uiautomator run JAR from Eclipse Export vs ANT build?

Tags: ant, jar, android-uiautomator

As title, is there any difference on the JAR that is created from Eclipse Export function vs ANT build if i were to run it with uiautomator?
Referring to [Android UI Testing](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html), I try to build JAR using ANT but i encounter [some problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792445/running-ant-build-gives-package-org-junit-does-not-exist) and couldnt fix it. So, i try to use Eclipse Export function to create the JAR and run it with Uiautomator. But then, i'm getting [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356650/android-uiautomator-runtest-error-didnt-find-classs). I've been googling around and cracking my head to get over this error so that i can test my stuff. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: The jar exported by using android ANT build.xml creates a .dex file in the jar. When you export from eclipse it will create a normal Java jar and I guess android(dalvik vm) does not understand this. If you want to avoid the head ache of building jar and executing you can try  [UIAutomator-bot](http://uiautomator-bot.blogspot.in/2014/08/create-and-execute-uiautomator-test.html)

Comment: I've tried your UiAutomator-bot, but when i try to run, it prompt me asking to perform ant build. But, when i try to do ant build, it failed saying build.xml does not exist.

Comment: As you were not able to build with ANT too, I suspect the problem is with your SDK. Please update your SDK and check.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve my problem by adding a AndroidManifest.xml to the project and i can then build JAR using ANT. The JAR runs perfectly with uiautomator