# Uiautomator Didn't find class <class> on path DexPathList

Tags: java, android, ant, jar, android-uiautomator

I am currently developing a Java project in order to perform automatic screenshots of my Android application, however, when performing the uiautomator command:

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest AutoScreenshot.jar -c test.ScreenshotRoutine
```

I am getting the following error:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.RuntimeException
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=Didn't find class "test.ScreenshotRoutine" on pa
th: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file
"/system/framework/uiautomator.jar", zip file "/data/local/tmp/AutoSc
reenshot.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib]]
INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
```

I have already searched everywhere and lost around 1 day around this issue. It seems that the answers around these kind of questions are over 1 year old and none of the solutions have worked for me.
I have followed the examples found [here](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/02/08/uiautomator-in-eclipse/) and [here](http://university.utest.com/android-ui-testing-uiautomatorviewer-and-uiautomator/), and changed the project slightly and have the following project structure:

```
src
 |- test
   |- <class extending UiAutomatorTestCase>
   |- interfaces
   |- routines
   |- utils
```

My ANT file for generating the JAR file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="AutoScreenshot.makejar" basedir=".">
    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="libs.dir" value="libs"/>
    <property name="root.dir" value="build"/>
    <property name="jar.dir" value="${root.dir}/jar"/>
    <property name="jar.file" value="${jar.dir}/AutoScreenshot.jar"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${root.dir}/classes"/>

    <path id="jars-classpath">
        <fileset dir="${libs.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${root.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>

        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" target="1.8" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath refid="jars-classpath"/>
        </javac>
        <jar jarfile="${jar.file}" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${libs.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
            <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" includes="**/*.class" />
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

Inside my Java project, I have created a ´libs´ folder which holds:

- android.jar;
- junit.jar;
- uiautomator.jar.

Am I missing something, where am I missing it?
If you need any other file you consider relevant, please feel free to ask.

***UPDATE #1 - Add batch file content***

Here is what I have in the batch file I've done in order to compile and upload the jar file

```
@echo off
echo CLEANING PROJECT
call ant clean

echo COMPILING JAR FILE
call ant compile

echo PUSHING JAR FILE TO DEVICE
call adb push "D:\Workspaces\...\build\jar\AutoScreenshot.jar" /data/local/tmp/

echo EXECUTING JAR FILE ON DEVICE
call adb shell uiautomator runtest /data/local/tmp/AutoScreenshot.jar -c test.ScreenshotRoutine#runRoutine -e lang en
```

***Many thanks in advance.***

Comment: what is you class name, package name ?

Comment: Hi @Rilwan, the class name was "ScreenshotRoutine", and the package name "test". The folders structure is in the original post, 3rd grayed out area code.

Comment: so inside the class ScreenshotRoutine, which method you want to run ? is the method starts with "test" ? if you want to run a specific method inside class ScreenshotRoutine, pls try `adb shell uiautomator runtest AutoScreenshot.jar -c test.ScreenshotRoutine#methodname`.

Comment: It was intended to run a method called `runRoutine()`, which was annotated with the `@Test` annotation. Is the annotation not relevant? Should I make is explicit which method to run when calling the `adb shell uiautomator`?

Comment: @Rilwan, even executing `adb shell uiautomator runtest AutoScreenshot.jar -c test.ScreenshotRoutine#runRoutine`, it gives me the error in the 2nd grayed out area code of the original post :(

Comment: Something is wrong that is sure,because it works for everyone. Just to double conform- you tried "ant clean build", and pushed jar file correctly to /data/local/tmp/. ?

Comment: @Rilwan, just edited my original post in order to include the content of the batch file I am using in order to compile and upload the jar file to the device.

Comment: just wonder-.  how did you add uiautomator.jar file ? Eclipse>Libraries>Add External jars>path_to_uiautomator.jar .

Comment: Hi @Rilwan, as a matter of fact, I copied the uiautomator.jar to a libs folder within the project and added it as an external jar yes. Currently, since the project have been exported to Android Studio, I was trying to perform the tests using espresso, but I've been having other issues. I think I should begin to try out and test on a personal project I am about to start.

Comment: i see.. Please update here too if you succeed. just wonder what is the problem in your project.

Comment: must be the “test.ScreenshotRoutine#runRoutine ” was wrong with you test project.I has been meet the same